# Transform cell characters into column titles in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have been working on this for two days now and still cannot find the answer.  Here is my problem:

I have a set of data that is created by a function for automatically extracting some data from a source.  It looks like this:

```
data

Week starting    Position                Title
 2013-01-05         1                    HAPPY
 2013-01-05         2               SKYSCRAPER
 2013-01-05         3              HEY BROTHER
 2013-01-05         4                 TRUMPETS
 2013-01-05         5              THE MONSTER
 2013-01-05         6   SOMEWHERE ONLY WE KNOW
 2013-01-12         1                    HAPPY
 2013-01-12         2               SKYSCRAPER
 2013-01-12         3              HEY BROTHER
 2013-01-12         4                 TRUMPETS
 2013-01-12         5              THE MONSTER
 2013-01-12         6   SOMEWHERE ONLY WE KNOW
    ...            ...                ...
```

I want to transpose the data like this so that I can run some time series analyses:

```
Week starting   HAPPY  SKYSCRAPER  HEY BROTHER   TRUMPETS   THE MONSTER    SOMEWHERE ONLY WE KNOW
2013-01-05         1      2             3            4         5                    6
2013-01-12         1      2             3            4         5                    6
   ...           ...     ...           ...          ...       ...                  ...
```

This is one way that I can think of for analysing this data set.  Please feel free to suggest any other ways.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Checkout the `reshape2` package. Here's a link on [how to convert from long to wide](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at `?reshape`

For instance:

```
reshape(data, v.names="Position", timevar="Title", idvar="Week.starting", 
        direction="wide")
```